# Is it possible to make pane/column dividers/separators wider in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

In Nautilus I struggle to select the divider/separator between columns or panels. Can something be done about it?

Comment: I think is determined by the theme, you mean the separator between the sidebar and the window canvas or the column separator when in "list" mode?

Comment: @UriHerrera: The one between panes in two-pane mode.